# How to access browser windows which are already open?

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser

I am writing some code in Python3. While I run the script, there are a few browser windows that are open already (say Chrome browser). These browser windows are not opened through an automated software like say Selenium but have been opened manually by user already. How do I access these browsers? After accessing these browsers, I want to perform some task on the webpages that are opened in these browser, which I intend to using xpath or such other method. But presently struggling to access these browser windows that have been opened manually.

Comment: To my knowledge: you can't. You need to open your own browser using f.e. selenium.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the browsers?

Comment: You might be able to use [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) to do what's needed.

Comment: @andreihondrari: I have a browser window where I log into a website and then I want script to take over the control of the browser to do some stuff once I have logged in.

Comment: @SanketBorkar yes but for what purpose? Perhaps you need to do some javascript pulling or some websockets that can monitor in the browser events triggered from the server/backend.

Comment: @martineau: how can I use Pyautogui for this. As far as I can think, I can click the browser window using moveTo function and make the browser window "active". However, beyond that, how do I take control of the browser, say finding elements, clicking on them etc.?

Comment: Sanket: It would allow you interact with the application through the browser's GUI—so you would be limited to what's available with that. You could, for example, determine the current URL being viewed. Making the browser app "active" is an OS dependent operation, and would require something specific like the PyWin32.